# how to overcome this exception

Tags: java, sdk

i am using a third part SDK with my java application.The providers of sdk provided me exe file that i installed and one java project.I installed the exefile.
Now when i run the code i get a dialog box showing error

```
Excepting a absulut path for library AKSSDK.dll
No AKSSDK in java.library.path
could not load load library AKSSDK
```

how do i resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add `AKSSDK.dll` to your `PATH` environment variable.

It would look like this:

```
echo %PATH%
C:\xyz\;C:\other\etc\etc;C:\Your\Path\To\AKSSDK.dll
```

**EDIT**

To modify your environment variable you have to go to:

MyComputer/RightClick/Properties/Advanced/EnvironmentVariables

[image]
<sub>(source: [vlaurie.com](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/graphics/envvar.gif))</sub>

And modify the existing  `Path` under System variables

See this tutorial for more details: http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm

I have had problems with the white space of ( Program files ) in the past. If possible install your SDK on something like `C:\SondaSDK` or `C:\You\SondaSDK`

That way you shouldn't have problems.

Comment: i have set the path to C:\Program Files\Sonda\Sonda SDK SE but still geting same problem

Comment: i have added the new environment variable. but i cant see the new path when i do echo %path%.Do i need to restart the pc?

Comment: Not the whole PC, but if you are running this from a command-prompt window that was open before you made the change, you'll need to close it and open a new one to see the change.

Comment: Also, the spaces in "C:\Program Files\Sonda\Sonda SDK SE" are going to screw things up - you can either copy the SDK to another location without spaces, if possible; or surround the path with quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You need to run `java` with the following configuration:

```
java -Djava.library.path={where your library is}
```

Note the above is the *directory* where your library is, not the full path name of the library!

Comment: Brian is correct.  All I know is every time I try and use machine-coded libraries in Java, I run into the same problems, and it is a pain to deal with.  Try different configurations of the value, and if the path has spaces it must be encoded in quotes.

Comment: I have successfully run native code by modifying the path environment variable directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the path to this value by starting with

java -Djava.library.path=PATH_TO_LIBRARY